# HTML input text tag can't be initialized

Tags: javascript, html, requirejs, jinja2

I'm having a problem with initializing some INPUT text type tags. After loading the page, the value in the input is not visible. If I view the source of the HTML page, the value is present. If I change the INPUT type to button and back, the value become visible.

```
<label for="contact_name">Contact</label><input type="text" id="contact_name" value="{{ name }}"/>
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

<s>It happened because I made a silly mistake. The INPUT tags in question have a handler bound to `keypress` event with `addEventListener`. The problem was with the variables pointing to functions I used for handlers, they were set to `undefined` so this bit of unexpected behavior popped out.</s>

Not strictly related to jinja&require.js but I tagged them for completeness. I'm using Firefox 53.0.2 64 bit, Windows 7 x64.

<s>Yak shaving done for today.</s>

Firefox threw me a few curve balls. The problem was down to autofill, introducing the `autocomplete="off"` attribute things are working as expected now.